# Are the magnitudes of the forces in activity in the two sides of a piston always the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

This question has come to my mind when I was learning about pressure-volume work.
I was told that the pressures applied on both sides of a massless piston is always the same. So, since
***F = P/A***,
I have infered that the forces have the same magnitudes.
And since they are opposite in direction, the piston should be inert.
But, alas, it could move if a gas is in expansion (P-V work) inside the cylinder.
So,... Why?

N.B:
I nearly have no background in gas yet, literally.
Assuming that the only work that can occur is P-V Work.

Comment: *"Are the magnitudes of the forces in activity in the two sides of a piston always the same?"* They might be (in which case no motion) or they might not be (in which case motion and work). I'm not sure what you're question is.

Comment: @Gert , The complete question could be: If the magnitude of the pressure in each side of the piston is equal, could the intensity of the forces be different?

Comment: *I was told that the pressures applied on both sides of a massless piston is always the same.* From where? It is likely you have dropped the context of this statement and this is where your confusion lies. It most likely is talking about systems at equilibrium.

Comment: Based on this question and your last one, I would suggest reading about [quasi-static processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process)

Comment: @AaronStevens The title of the chapter was "Thermochemistry" and the subchapter "Quantifying Heat-Work" and the sub-subchapter "Work: Pressure-Volume Work". So it was mostly about P-V works under a constant pressure. There was nothing about system equilibrium. But my question is about it.

Comment: @AaronStevens I read it. It is it. Thanks for the ressource.

Comment: If $F_A$ and $F_B$ represent the pressure forces on the two sides of the piston, then a force balance on the piston yields $F_A-F_B=ma$.  If the piston has zero mass (m=0), this reduces to $F_A=F_B$, irrespective of the acceleration.  So, for a massless piston, the pressures on the two sides of the piston must always be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't quite get your question but as of what I understand you seem to ask how does a piston move if pressure on either sides is zero.

If that is what you're asking I can answer it.
Well In basic thermodynamics most of the processes like adiabatic, isothermal, isobaric and isovolumetric are very ideal. They don't occur in real life without very specific lab conditions. However, these ideal processes are called "Quasi Static processes".

A Quasi Static, as it's name says is "False static" i.e the process is so slow that:

1. It takes infinite time for completion
2. The process attains equilibrium after each step.

Thus, in such processes, the pressure on either sides of a piston is considered to be equal.
With the reason of considering the pressures equal, the remaining part is just basic mechanics.

Net force being zero means the particle is in equilibrium, but that only implies to the ACCELERATION being zero and not the velocity. "Moving the piston slowly" implies that we are moving it without exerting any force on it. This concept is again, only an ideal speculation that doesn't occur in real life. Such speculations are made to approximate the value desired and hence slowly working out way out to the exact version which requires much complex analysis.

Let me know if I misinterpreted your question.